# Unable to commit a container in Docker with Jar file

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I have a created a Jar file using spring boot project and the container name is `clever_bohr` and i want to commit the container using the `--change='CMD ["java","-jar","/tmp/hello-world-rest-api.jar"]'`
However it's throwing error as below

```
C:\Development\Docker\docker-crash-course-master\01-hello-world-rest-api>docker commit --change='CMD ["java","-jar","/tmp/hello-world-rest-api.jar"]' clever_bohr clever_bohr2:latest
"docker commit" requires at least 1 and at most 2 arguments.
See 'docker commit --help'.

Usage:  docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]

Create a new image from a container's changes
```

However when i remove the `--change` command , it's working fine. I have verified and the jar file is present in tmp directory as below

```
C:\Development\Docker\docker-crash-course-master\01-hello-world-rest-api>docker container exec clever_bohr ls /tmp
hello-world-rest-api.jar
```

Comment: Using `docker commit` at all is not really a best practice.  If you write a Dockerfile and use `docker build` to build images, you can add that to source control and it will be reproducible (and you don't need weird syntax to include Dockerfile commands on the command line).  Other Java SO questions tend to have very short Dockerfiles (based on a jar file built on the host) and you might look into that approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows, it could be the problem because of single quotes in command line.

Try the below option for windows:

```sh
docker commit --change="CMD ("java" "-jar" "/tmp/hello-world-rest-api.jar")" clever_bohr clever_bohr2:latest
```

Comment: Shouldn't these quotation marks be escaped? Like `--change="CMD (\"java\" \"-jar\" \"/tmp/hello-world-rest-api.jar\")"`

Comment: Not necessary .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Java path wasn't set.
Try using "/usr/bin/java" instead of Java.

Or maybe your double quotes character is not " rather something similar looking.